# cinnamon doesn't start, bumblebee problem

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia, graphics

I have Linux Mint 13 64 bit version with cinnamon, NVdia Geforce 320m, proprietary driver 304.54 if I'm not mistaken. I installed bumblebee following this guide:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia linux-headers-generic
```

Rebooted, and now I have 640x480 resolution, half-broken gnome 3 was loaded (there are no buttons to log out or reboot, no animations of course). When I try to run `nvidia-settings` I get:

```
You do not appear to be using the NVIDIA X driver.  
Please edit your X configuration file (just run `nvidia-xconfig` as root),
and restart the X server.
```

What shall I do to fix this? I want my discrete graphics card and cinnamon back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know I'm late, but the fix probably was changing bumblebee config around. Sometimes there's a desync where you are officially using a different driver than Bumblebee thinks you are, and when it tries to do stuff it points at inaccurate libraries, wrong drivers and overall armageddon ensues. Bumblebee config is under `/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf` and you wanna set the used driver in shared `[bumblebeed]` section with `Driver=nvidia` (or nouveau) and then the precise driver and its libs in the specific driver section `[driver-nvidia]` or `[driver-nouveau]`). In the case of nvidia-304 it's `KernelDriver=nvidia-304`, `LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-304:/usr/lib32/nvidia-304` and `XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-304/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules`.

**Remember to always update this when switching drivers around!**

I just fixed my setup this way, so I hope necrobumping this will help people searching for the same thing as me.

Comment: Necrobumping ftw! :D

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get --purge remove bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia` might be a first step in trying to get things back to how they were.  Other than that, the [Bumblebee Wiki](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki), particularly the [Reporting Issues](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Reporting-Issues), [FAQ](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/FAQ), and [Troubleshooting](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Troubleshooting) pages are your best bet.

Comment: Only removing this packages didn't help - I reinstalled video drivers and now everything works as it worked before bumblebee installation.

Comment: But did you use `--purge` when removing it?  Removing the package without purging the configuration is likely the reason it was still broken.

Comment: As I think I purged everything related to bumblebee - I typed `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge && sudo ppa-purge ppa:bumblebee/stable`

Comment: `ppa-purge`, despite its name, does **not** actually remove packages.  It only removes the named PPA from your `apt` configuration, then **reinstalls** any packages that have a version present in your remaining repositories.  If there's a package that was provided by the PPA and not part of your standard repository, like `bumblebee` and `bumblebee-nvidia`, `ppa-purge` won't remove them.  See [Bug 945967](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ppa-purge/+bug/945967) for confirmation.  Run `dpkg -l | grep bumblebee` to see what bits of Bumblebee are still installed.  If it shows no output, it's fully gone.